# Wordcloud2, how to fix order of words when exporting or rerunning code

Tags: r, word-cloud

I'm using the package wordcloud2 (with set.seed(123)), but when I export or re-run my code the overall shape or order of words change, is there a comment to prevent this from happening? I used the code below;

```
wordcloud2(data = dat, 
           color = dat$color,
           size = .5,
           shuffle = FALSE)
```

Hope some one can help to fix this randomness.

Comment: Could you fix this?